expected input to be a TRUE/FALSE but got the number 0 instead
I got the netlogo code from ChatGPT related to habitat fragmentation. This is a code that prevents animals from going out on the road if they are on the ecological corridor. However, an error message pops up in
if on-corridor and [road] of patch-here [
    bk 1 
].

This is the error I'm receiving:

AND expected input to be a TRUE/FALSE but got the number 0 instead.
error while consumer 409 running AND
called by procedure MOVE-CONSUMERS
called by procedure GO
called by Button 'go'

to move-consumers
  ask consumers [
    rt random 360
    fd 1
    if [corridor] of patch-here [
      set on-corridor true 
    ]
    if not [corridor] of patch-here and not [habitat] of patch-here [
      set on-corridor false 
    ]

    if on-corridor and [road] of patch-here [
      bk 1 
    ]

    if not ([habitat] of patch-here or [corridor] of patch-here) [ die ]
    set energy energy - 1.0
    if [habitat] of patch-here = false and [corridor] of patch-here = false [
      set energy energy - 0.8
    ]
    if energy <= 0 [ die ]
  ]
end


Please take the [tour] and read [ask], and then edit to provide a [mcve] with your own work, including all relevant details. Right now, you're asking the Community to run and debug code that was AI-generated.
